# Regularisation parameter Ridge Regression

Tags: regression, regularization, ridge-regression, online-algorithms

Background: I am trying to apply ridge regression in on-line mode. In batch learning we use cross-validation to calculate regularisation parameter.

Is there a way to calculate regularisation parameter for ridge regression iteratively?

Comment: Can you describe better what you want? I doubt that you can choose regularization that way, an online algorithm would have to use a prechoose reg parameter